Windows 10 Qemu Intel haxm "-accel hax: invalid accelerator hax"
I'm trying to get Intel Haxm acceleration working on qemu/windows 10.
I followed this guide..
https://www.qemu.org/2017/11/22/haxm-usage-windows/
I have Virtualization enabled in bios, hyper-v disabled, and haxm 7.8.0 installed. I have qemu 9.0.0 installed form binary installer from..
https://qemu.weilnetz.de/w64/
when i try to launch a VM with option -accel hax i get this message:
C:\Program Files\qemu\qemu-system-x86_64.exe: -accel hax: invalid accelerator hax

This is the complete powershell script i'm using to launch the VM.
& "qemu-system-x86_64" `
    -m 2048M `
    -nic user,model=virtio `
    -drive file=./images/endeavouros.qcow2 `
    -cdrom EndeavourOS_Gemini-2024.04.20.iso `
    -accel hax


You are tracking Intel Haxm was discontinued a number of years ago. Are you sure qemu still supports it? Even when it was supported haxm did not support 64-bit guests.

Wow, i've been trying to get this to work for 2 days. https://wiki.qemu.org/ChangeLog/8.0 " "The HAXM project has been retired, and -accel hax has therefore been deprecated."

https://wiki.qemu.org/ChangeLog/8.0

The HAXM project has been retired, and -accel hax has therefore been
deprecated.


Use whpx instead, altho that's finicky and broken - have to pass `kernel-irqchip=off`` and even that's wonky
